# How do I show this sequence converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $A=[-1,1]$, and $f:A\to\Bbb{R}$ a continuous function, such that $f(0)=0$. I need to show that $g_n$ converges uniformly on $A$, when $$g_n(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1+nx^2}$$

I honestly don't get this one. The only thing that I can think off is pretty far fetched : Supposing the limit function is $f(x) = 0$. Then, because $f(x)$ is continuous, it attains a maximum value on $A$, and therefore so does $g_n(x)$. It seems like $g_n(x)$ is maximized when the denominator is minimized, and the numerator maximized. At this point we might look at what happens when $x\to 0$, apply definitions of continuity etc. The idea is to of course show that the sequence $$M_n=\sup_{x\in A}\vert g_n(x)-0\vert$$

goes to zero as $n\to \infty$. But since I can't deduce what the limit function is, this test will not work. Help please.

Comment: But you can see from the definition of $g_n(x)$ that its pointwise limit (which I would call $g$, not $f$) is $0$ everywhere, which is what you need to know.  That's why it's important that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: There's a the theorem that a function continuous on a closed interval is uniformly continuous. I forget what its called. Regardless, prove that all $g_n$ are continuous and apply that theorem, you are good to go.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed: Each function $g_n$ is uniformly continuous. But that does not imply that the sequence $(g_n)$ *converges uniformly.*

Comment: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use $f(0) = 0$ to get a uniform bound of the $g_n$ near the origin, and the general boundedness of $f$ to get a uniform bound on the rest of $A$, away from the origin.

So let $\epsilon > 0$.

- First, from the continuity of $f$ and $f(0) = 0$ it follows that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $|x| < \delta$. It follows that for $|x| < \delta$ and all $n$
  $$
   |g_n(x)| \le \frac{\epsilon}{1+nx^2} \le \epsilon \, .
  $$
- Second, $f$ is bounded on $A$, say $|f(x)| \le M$. It follows that for $|x| \ge \delta$
  $$
   |g_n(x)| \le \frac{M}{1+nx^2} \le \frac{M}{1+n \delta^2} \, ,
  $$
  and that is also $< \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.

This shows that $|g_n(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x \in A$ and all sufficiently large $n$, i.e. $g_n$ converges uniformly to zero.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, you are saying that the $N$ in $n\geq N$ will not depend on $x$, exactly because you cover all possible cases for $x$

Comment: @variations: Exaclty. If $N$ is chosen such that $\frac{M}{1+N \delta^2} < \epsilon$ then $|g_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$ and all $x \in A$.